# failed to send SMS in android app

Tags: android, sms

I was trying to write an app to send a SMS when a button clicked.
so I wrote a class that implements OnClickListener interface and in the onClick methode I wrote this code:

```
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
     new Intent(context, ContactsActivity.class), 0);
     SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
     sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, text, pi, null);
```

in here context is the activity that I got an instance of my OnClickListener.
so my app crashes in the last line!!

I even putted:

```
        number = number.replace(" ", "");
    number = number.replace("-", "");
```

before the code to make the number that I've got from contact list look correct! but didn't help!

and I've checked my number is correct!

p.s. I added these permissions to the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

UPDATE:
log details:

> 01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid message body
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:82)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at com.saeedFri.groupsms.SendClickListeneer.sendSMS(SendClickListeneer.java:58)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at com.saeedFri.groupsms.SendClickListeneer.sendSMSes(SendClickListeneer.java:38)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at com.saeedFri.groupsms.SendClickListeneer.onClick(SendClickListeneer.java:32)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   01-26 21:01:39.959: E/AndroidRuntime(6470):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

thanks in advance.

Comment: is Internet permission required?

Comment: @PadmaKumar, I don't see why it be required!

Comment: @JoxTraex I added the stacktrace, thanks for your consideration (I'm not sure "consideration" belong here or not :) )

Comment: @ Padma Kumar Internet permission is not required for sending sms.

Comment: may be your number or text is empty thats why its giving IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sendTextMessage` method will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the **first** or **third**  parameter is empty.

As seen in the documentation...

```
public void sendTextMessage (String destinationAddress, String scAddress,
String text, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent)

Throws
IllegalArgumentException    if destinationAddress or text are empty
```

Ensure that the  the first and third parameters are not empty. Thatis most likely the problem.

In your question you have said you made sure your `number` variable is correct. In that case, your `text` variable must be empty. Post your declaration of it.